# Como Modificar un Option de un Select desde Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Me gustaria cambiar el texto del option desde jquery , hay alguna manera de hacerlo.

```
option value="0"  TEXTO /option
```

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido a Stackoverflow, puedes capturar el elemento select primero que todo, y hecho ésto, hay varias maneras de modificar el contenido de los option, ejm:

1. `$("select [value='0']").append("Lo que desees ponerle");`
2. `$("select option[value=0]").text("Lo que desees ponerle");`
3. `$("select option:contains("//El texto que tienes en éste momento")").append("El nuevo texto que deseas poner");`